# Construct $\mathbb{RP}^n$

Tags: geometry, group-actions

Has anyone an idea of how to make $\mathbb{RP}^n $ using an action of the multiplicative group of nonzero integrers acting on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}-\{0\}$ that gives you $\mathbb{RP}^n $ (must be the orbit space)?

Comment: What's your definition of $\mathbb{RP}^n$?

Comment: Acting by the integers?  You can identify points in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}-\{\mathbf{0}\}$ by non-zero (real) scalings (note the dimension increase) and produce $\mathbb{R}P^n$.

Comment: It doesn't matter the definition. Could be for example $ \frac{\mathbb{S}^n}{\{I,A\}}$ (identity and the antipode)

Comment: Is the $\Bbb R^{n-1}$ in the question actually supposed to be that?

Comment: What makes you think such an action exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’m going to be bold and contend that no such construction exists.  There’s no way the quotient of an $n-1$ dimensional manifold by a discrete group is going to create an $n$ dimensional manifold.